# how to solve Exception has occurred: UnicodeEncodeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding

I tried to run this code

```
  ins = insightsearch.Analysis(
  df='encodedreviews.csv',
  column_name="Text",vader=False
  )

  # returns html file with insights visualisation
  ins.review_analyze()
```

with this csv file

```
App_Name,rating,date,variation,Text,feedback
Alexa,5,31-Jul-18,Charcoal Fabric ,Love my Echo!,1
Alexa,5,31-Jul-18,Charcoal Fabric ,Loved it!,1
Alexa,4,31-Jul-18,Walnut Finish ,"Sometimes while playing a game, you can answer a question correctly but Alexa says you got it wrong and answers the same as you.  I like being able to turn lights on and off while away from home.",1
Alexa,5,31-Jul-18,Charcoal Fabric ,"I have had a lot of fun with this thing. My 4 yr old learns about dinosaurs, i control the lights and play games like categories. Has nice sound when playing music as well.",1
Alexa,5,31-Jul-18,Charcoal Fabric ,Music,1
Alexa,5,31-Jul-18,Heather Gray Fabric ,"I received the echo as a gift. I needed another Bluetooth or something to play music easily accessible, and found this smart speaker. Can’t wait to see what else it can do.",1
```

but I keep getting this error

> ```
> Exception has occurred: UnicodeEncodeError
> 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4' in position 282537: character maps to <undefined>
>   File "C:\Users\rkono\OneDrive\Pictures\New folder\sen.py", line 12, in <module>
>     ins.review_analyze()
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4' in position 282537: character maps to <undefined>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for the UnicodeEncodeError in your code is to specify the encoding format when you read or write the file. This error happens when a string has characters that can't be encoded with the given format. You can solve this by using the encoding parameter when you open the file.

```
with open('encodedreviews.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Comment: not fixed sadddd